# How to remove the style effect with javascript or jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How to remove the style with jQuery or JavaScript in order to display the `div` element?

```
  <div style="display: none">display something </div>
```

If you know ,please share with me . Thanks

PS：Before ,I have tried with jquery.show(), but the effect is a big blank over there

Answer (score 2):

Try like

```
$('div').css('display','block');
```

Better you give an `class` or `id` to the specific div and try like

**Using Id :**

```
$('#div_id').css('display','block');
```

**Using Class :**

```
$('.div_class').css('display','block');
```

Answer (score 1):

You better assign some `id` to your div to make it unique and keep the change upto desired element. You can use `style` property of javascript `DOM` object to access display or other sub-property.

```
<div style="display: none" id="id" >display something </div>
```

*Using javascript*

```
document.getElementById('id').style.display = 'block';
```

*Using JQuery, you can use id selector*

```
$('#id').css('display','block');
```

If you just want to change display property you can use show / hide method instead.

```
$('#id').show();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementById('id of the div').style.display = 'block';
```

should give an Id to the div

Another method is

```
$('div').css('display','block');
```

Answer (score 0):

first you need to identify the `div` for that give the div an ID or a class attribute

```
<div style="display: none" id="mydiv">display something </div>
```

then jQuery

```
jQuery(function($){
    $('#mydiv').show()
})
```

Comment: Thanks, I have tied that method before ,but it turn out a blank over there.

Comment: @andyqee this should be written in dom ready handler

Answer (score 0):

jQuery provide shortcut for this:

```
$('div').show();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can show it with the jQuery `show` method, like this:

```
$('div').show();
```

This will show all `div`s on your page. If you want to only show this particular div, you could give it an id, like this:

```
<div style="display: none" id="myDiv">display something </div>
```

And then show it like this:

```
$('#myDiv').show();
```

Comment: Thanks, I have tied that method before ,but it turn out a blank over there.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to show the div you can do this:

```
$("div").show();
```

If you want to remove the style tag completely:

```
$("div").removeAttr("style");
```

Note: Id recommend giving your div an id or class otherwise either of the above 2 options will do it to all div's not just this one.

e.g: `<div id="myDiv" style="display: none">display something </div>`

then you would change that div liek this:

```
$("#myDiv").show();
```

Answer (score 0):

To remove an style effect :

```
$('div').css('display','');
```

From jQuery doc :

> $( "#mydiv" ).css( "color", "" ) — removes that property from an
>   element if it has already been directly applied.

[**See doc**](http://api.jquery.com/css/)